# How do you personalize a banner that is on multiple pages?

Tags: personalization

I'm using Sitecore 8.1 Original Release, and I've created a banner advertisement that I want to display on every page of my website. The banner is using personalization to determine which variation it should show. I've got that all working just fine from my home page. Here's the problem that I've got:

How do I put this same banner (with the same personalization rules) on every page of my website? It seems inefficient to have to go through every page and have to put the same personalization rules on each page individually.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a base template and the `__Standard Values` for that. After that you should add your banner's rendering at the presentation of the `__Standard Values` and set the personalization rules for those. You need do that once and the other pages will inherit that from base template.

Comment: This has gotten me 80% of the way to where I want to be. My issue now is that I've already got layouts on my templates, and from what I can tell, Sitecore doesn't allow you to inherit more than one presentation definition from the `__StandardValues` setting (At least, I can't figure out how to do that)

Comment: But you have answered my original question, so this gets me close enough, I think. Thank you!